# Overriding user macro by setting an environment variable

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I defined a library location as a user macro and this works fine.
However, I needed a way to override this definition by a value of an environment variable. (If this environment variable is not defined, the said predefined user macro value should be used.)

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way, but you will have to edit the project file directly, e.g. via context menu "Unload" on the project in the solution explorer and then open it in the VS (also in the context menu, I do not remember the precise name).

The project file is a MSBuild (XML) file. Environment variables can be accessed directly as properties via `$(<Name>)`. The user macro values end up in properties, too. Their values can be overridden after they have been set which normally happens inside a `PropertyGroup` element.

Say your user macro is `FooDir`. Then you will find something like this in the project file

```
<PropertyGroup>
  ...
  <FooDir>...</FooDir>
  ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

If you now add

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <FooDir Condition="'$(FOO_DIR)' != ''">$(FOO_DIR)</FooDir>
</PropertyGroup>
```

immediately afterwards, it will pick up the environment variable `FOO_DIR` as default value to override the user macro if it is not empty.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171459.aspx

Comment: This solution works. However, it uses an environment variable with a name that is different than the user macro name, and for consistency I would like to use the same name. Is it possible?

Comment: Well, you can remove the added `PropertyGroup` element and add the inverted condition to the first definition of the property as mentioned on the MSDN page. If the environment variable has the same name, the property already exists non-empty and will not be set.
But I do not know if you can still edit the user macro value with the VS if you do this.